# How to make a wait for an attribute? java + webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, automation

i need to make a wait until attribute receives value and got error about "until". What i do wrong? Thank you

```
List<WebElement> messages = driver.findElements(By.className("message-item"));
//select last message
WebElement lastMessage = messages.get(messages.size() - 1);
//wait for last message attribute received failed
WebDriverWait waitLastMessage = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
waitLastMessage.until(lastMessage.getAttribute("data-deliverystatus").contains("failed"));
//here i check vaules of attribute
Assert.assertEquals(lastMessage.getAttribute("data-deliverystatus"), "failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

`until` method receives `ExpectedConditions`, not any `boolean`. You can do something like that (not tested)

```
private ExpectedCondition<Boolean> waitForAttribute(final WebElement element) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return element.getAttribute("data-deliverystatus").contains("failed");
        }
    };
}

WebDriverWait waitLastMessage = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
waitLastMessage.until(waitForAttribute);
```